# How do I make jupyter-hub access my private docker image repository?

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kubernetes-helm

I want to deploy my own image on JuPyter-hub. However, I need to deploy it to some registry so that the `image puller` of JHub can pull it from there. In my case, the registry is private. Although I am able to push the image to my registry, I don't know how will I make the jupyterhub release and deployment be able to pull the image.

I tried reading this doc (https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-deploy-docker) but it could not help me understand how am I to add authentication in the jupyter hub deployment.

I deploy `jhub` with this command:

```
#  Suggested values: advanced users of Kubernetes and Helm should feel
# free to use different values.
RELEASE=jhub
NAMESPACE=jhub

helm upgrade --install $RELEASE jupyterhub/jupyterhub \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE  \
  --version=0.8.0 \
  --values jupyter-hub-config.yaml
```

where the jupyter-hub-config.yaml is as follows:

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "abcd"
singleuser:
  image:
    name: jupyter/datascience-notebook
    tag: some_tag
  lifecycleHooks:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", 'ipython profile create; cd ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup; echo ''run_id = "sample" ''> aviral.py']
```

The helm chart is available here: https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/jupyterhub-0.8.2.tgz

And the tree of this helm chart is:

```
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── jupyter-hub-config.yaml
├── requirements.lock
├── schema.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── hub
│   │   ├── configmap.yaml
│   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   ├── image-credentials-secret.yaml
│   │   ├── netpol.yaml
│   │   ├── pdb.yaml
│   │   ├── pvc.yaml
│   │   ├── rbac.yaml
│   │   ├── secret.yaml
│   │   └── service.yaml
│   ├── image-puller
│   │   ├── _daemonset-helper.yaml
│   │   ├── daemonset.yaml
│   │   ├── job.yaml
│   │   └── rbac.yaml
│   ├── ingress.yaml
│   ├── proxy
│   │   ├── autohttps
│   │   │   ├── _README.txt
│   │   │   ├── configmap-nginx.yaml
│   │   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   │   ├── ingress-internal.yaml
│   │   │   ├── rbac.yaml
│   │   │   └── service.yaml
│   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   ├── netpol.yaml
│   │   ├── pdb.yaml
│   │   ├── secret.yaml
│   │   └── service.yaml
│   ├── scheduling
│   │   ├── _scheduling-helpers.tpl
│   │   ├── priorityclass.yaml
│   │   ├── user-placeholder
│   │   │   ├── pdb.yaml
│   │   │   ├── priorityclass.yaml
│   │   │   └── statefulset.yaml
│   │   └── user-scheduler
│   │       ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │       ├── configmap.yaml
│   │       ├── deployment.yaml
│   │       ├── pdb.yaml
│   │       └── rbac.yaml
│   └── singleuser
│       ├── image-credentials-secret.yaml
│       └── netpol.yaml
├── test-99.py
├── validate.py
└── values.yaml
```

All I want to do is to make jupyterhub access my private repo using `secrets`. In this case, I do not know how to make this available to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Image pull secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod) can be used to pull a image from private registry.

Append the jupyter-hub-config.yam with the following blob.

```
imagePullSecret:
    enabled: true
    registry:
    username:
    email:
    password:
```

With the Value

username:AWS

password:`aws ecr get-login --region ${REGION} --registry-ids ${ACCOUNT} | cut -d' ' -f6`

Comment: Where will I use it?

Comment: https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/blob/master/jupyterhub/values.yaml#L54  here

Comment: As of now, I have access to a k8s cluster, I am able to deploy jhub on it.
What else should I do in order to make the image registry, say `secret-aviral/image1` available to my jhub?

Comment: in values.yaml file, you will enable it and provide the values for registry, user and password

Comment: there is another place here https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/blob/master/jupyterhub/values.yaml#L210

Comment: i think its the second one, in the singleuser. testing it with second one at first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193511/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-aviral-srivastava).

Comment: the user was aws and password was via command -> `aws ecr get-login --region ap-south-1 --registry-ids some_no | cut -d' ' -f6`.
Note: in the image tag, give both image registry, and the demo